# Cannot convert string to char in c++?

Tags: c++, string, char, error-correction

Does anybody know what's wrong with this code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string a;
getline(cin, a);
for(;;)
{
    string x;
    x=1;
    string b;
    getline(cin, b);
    string c;
    getline(cin, c);
    string d;
    d=a+b;
    string e;
    e=b+c;
    if(b=="1")
    {
        return 0;
    }
    rename(d, e);
}
}
```

It says that the error is on the

```
rename(d,e);
```

part. And it gives an error

```
cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int rename(const char*, const char*)
```

So I'm assuming it can't convert string to char. Does anybody know how to do it and send the corrected part?

Comment: `rename(d.c_str(), e.c_str());`

Comment: Thanks, why not post this as an answer too so I can give you an upvote.

Comment: You should have posted what `rename` does. All that can be seen in your post is the signature of `rename`.  what @Sebastian Hoffmann says suits the signature, but does it produce the desired effect?

Comment: Rename renames a file in a location with something a person would enter. It's a bit complicated even I forgot how it worked so I rewrote the code. In my IDE.

Comment: so it is std::filesystem::rename then. That is one trouble with `using namespace std;`

Comment: @lakeweb It's the [rename](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/rename) from the C standard library (`stdio.h`)

Comment: @lakeweb it's `std::rename`  , and askers don't need to post details of standard functions. You could look up documentation if unfamiliar with the function

Comment: Hi @Blastfurnace, thanks. I guess I'll have to pay attention to that lib. I don't think I've used it in a forever, other than an occasional `printf`. The [Standard Library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header) is my goto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no implicit conversion from `std::string` to char pointer, you need to invoke it via a function call:

```
rename( d.c_str(), e.c_str() );
```