# "No suitable conversion function"

Tags: c++

I was trying to make a program that can open websites via running a command in the shell. But I get this error: "no suitable conversion function from "std::__1::string" to "const char *" exists". But the wierd this is that it still runs as i wanted it to, I just dont understand why?

code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string website;
    std::cout << "what website would you like to open?" << "\n";
    std::cin >> website;

    if (website.find("https://") != std::string::npos) {
        // Website contains "https"
    }
    else if (website.find("http://") != std::string::npos) {
        // Website contains "http"
    }
    else {
        website = "https://" + website;
    }

    std::string command = "open " + website;

    int returnCode = system(command);

    if (returnCode != 0) {
        // Handle error if needed
        std::cout << "Error executing command" << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I tried making the command function a const but that didn't seem to do it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a full and complete copy-paste of the build-log. And add comments in your shown code where you get the errors.

Comment: It doesn't compile but it runs correctly? That's very surprising; are you sure that's what's going on? Maybe you are running an old version of your code?

Comment: As a guess for your problem: `std::system` is an old C function, which have no idea about C++ classes or strings.

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60479563/509868)

Answer (score 0):

You should [access](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) the null-terminated character array of `std::string` through the `c_str()` method.

```
int returnCode = system(command.c_str());
```

What you are doing is undefined behaviour (even if it happens to work in this case).